# Which laptop make has the greatest ubuntu support at the moment?

Tags: laptop

I am running lubuntu on netbook and it has a few bugs with brightness and touchpad but I don't mind too much because it was cheap.

I need something a bit higher spec now so I have been looking into dell laptops for more support but I am not sure if there are others? Or even how good dell are with this?

Comment: Hi Magpie, this question will be very difficult to answer since many laptops have great support in Ubuntu. MANY, like a lot + 2 more. If you could be more specific it could help.

Comment: MY laptop, because I made it so ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I for one think that the best Ubuntu laptops are [System76](https://www.system76.com/). The customer service is outstanding, everything works out of the box and you have 3 different models to choose from and configure the specs at your personal taste. Quality/price is the best out there. Try to find the same specs for same price with other major vendors (dell, HP, etc...).

I am a proud owner of a System76 system and can truly tell you that you won't be disappointed. I am actually thinking in buying my second device (a 14' laptop for travelling).

Hope this is what you are looking for. They have a [support forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=341) if you have doubts and their support staff is very active there.

Enjoy!

Comment: again I could not use a system76 laptop as they are based outside the UK unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Dell's Ubuntu offerings are fairly paltry, http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/laptops.aspx?ref=us-eb-lt#!facets=80770~0~1791343&p=1. I would recommend purchasing from a company that fully supports Linux/Ubuntu, such as [System76](https://www.system76.com/laptops/), [Zareason](http://zareason.com/shop/Laptops/), [Think Penguin](https://www.thinkpenguin.com/catalog/notebook-computers-gnulinux), or [LinPC](http://linpc.us/notebook-systems). Personally, I can only vouch for System76, but I have been very pleased with their desktop offerings. So much so, that I made them our standard desktops where I work. They also have great, knowledgeable staff.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I don't think I can use those companies as they are not uk based, but I suspect you are right that it is better to look towards companies that specialise. I can see the point in tweaking yourself but as I haven;t managed to fully configure my netbook i wouldn't risk it with a more expensive laptop